# How to add PrintPageEventArgs into Form_Load c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an application which prints `listview` items and some pictures. In the first form, I fill listview and when I press the preview button it opens form 2 and prints my listview and other things.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\assda.jpg");
    Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
    d.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(10, 20, 195, 100), new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    d.Graphics.DrawString("xxxxx", new Font("Times New Romans", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(350, 60));
    }
```

I have to add `PrintPageEventArgs d` but when I add like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, PrintPageEventArgs d)
```

I get the following error:

```
No overload for 'Form1_Load' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
```

It shows the error in Form1.Designer.cs:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

Comment: You can't change the predefined event handlers at your will. Form.Load has only two arguments and there is nothing you can do to change this fact.

Comment: Why don't you raise your own event when Form1 loads?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack overflow. I edited your question to bring more focus on what you were asking. Please feel free to edit it further or reject my edits.

Comment: Form_Load and Print_Page (3 of 5) are 2 totally different events that should not happen at the same time and should not be related. This is what we call an [X/Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Thank you Dhara for your edit :)

Comment: The question makes no sense whatsoever.  Don't ask about the solution you had in mind, ask about the problem you want to solve.

Comment: I asked my problem,not ask about the solution in my mind....

Comment: There is no Form Load method overload available that takes PrintPageEventArgs as argument, so you can not use it like that. What you actually want to do?

Comment: I actually want to do is when I press preview button I want to print something but I cant use PrintPageEventArgs

Comment: _when I press preview button I want to print something_ Well that is a start. Now add a regular printing code and call it in the previewForm's load event. - Btw: I'm amazed nobody asked where `d.Graphics` might come from. Probably all were too confused about the idea to create the args out of thin air. ((which sometimes can be done, if one knows the weherefore and why..)). If you created it yourself: chances are it won't  even work anyway.

Comment: @DjSucuk, you want to display first item on page load and display more items on Preview button click, right? If yes, where is your listview with items or correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new .cs and write something like that ;

```
override protected void print(PrintPageEventArgs e){

    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\assda.jpg");
        Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
        d.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(10, 20, 195, 100), new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        d.Graphics.DrawString("xxxxx", new Font("Times New Romans", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(350, 60));
        }
```

Call this code where you want to use